# If $a_n\leq b_n$ then $\limsup a_n\leq \liminf b_n$

Tags: real-analysis, limsup-and-liminf

If $a_n\leq b_n$ then $\limsup a_n\leq \liminf b_n$

This is a statement in Royden, but I am not sure how to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I proved that you can take limsup and liminf of both sides. But those are not helpful in this case. Other than that, not sure what to do. Also I understand that some people just want their homework done but sometimes people simply do not know what to do. Like me, in this case. If you look at my posts you will see I always post ideas that I have, If I have them.

Comment: The statement is false: just pick $a_n=b_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: @Masacroso Well that is unexpected, thank you! It must be a misprint in Royden (p 23 for anyone curious)

Comment: @Masacroso Can you post this as an answer?